# oracle procedure returning table of custom data type record

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, record, custom-data-type

I created a custom  data type of the type "object"

```
create type myrecord is object(col1 varchar2(10),col2 varchar2(10));
```

I created a table which is of the type record

```
create type mytableobject is table of myrecord;
```

Now i have filled the table "mytableobject" with data using

```
"execute immediate" (select * from table1) bulk collect into mytableobject.
```

I want to return this mytableobject in a STORED procedure.

How do i achieve this?
And how do i call the procedure?

Comment: Why `execute immediate`, and why in double-quotes? What does your procedure look like at the moment, and how are you calling it - and from where?

Answer (score 4):

You can use your own type as an `OUT` parameter to a stored procedure. The table population you showed doesn't make much sense, so I think this is what you must really be doing:

```
create or replace procedure myproc(mytable out mytableobject) is
begin
  select myrecord(col1, col2)
  bulk collect into mytable
  from table1;
end myproc;
/
```

You can then call that from another procedure or anonymous block by declaring a local variable of that type and passing it in:

```
declare
  tab mytableobject;
begin
  myproc(tab);
end;
/
```

It seems more likely that you want a function, particularly since you mentioned returning it. That's pretty much the same:

```
create or replace function myfunc
return mytableobject is
  mytable mytableobject;
begin
  select myrecord(col1, col2)
  bulk collect into mytable
  from table1;

  return mytable;
end myfunc;
/

declare
  tab mytableobject;
begin
  tab := myfunc;
end;
/
```

But more usefully you can call the function from SQL:

```
select * from table(myfunc);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d1ff/1).