# SELECT procedure requires INSERT INTO?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle12c

I have this simple SELECT procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE CST_FEEDBACK
(
  LineID IN Integer
) AS
BEGIN

SELECT 
    T1.*
--  ,   Mgr.UserName as UserName
FROM F_Feedback T1
--LEFT JOIN tblUsers Mgr
--ON T1.EmpID = Mgr.EmpID

WHERE
    T1.Line_ID = LineID

ORDER BY T1.Comments_TS DESC;

END CST_FEEDBACK;
```

I am an Oracle n00b, we were using SQL Server in our shop but were suddenly forced to switch to Oracle.  I'm getting this message when I try to compile it:

> Error(7,1): PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT
>   statement

Can anyone tell me why this is happening, and if there's some way to get around it?

Comment: Because that is the syntax for PL/SQL. What do you plan to do with the selected data? And which version of Oracle are you using (the database, not the SQL Developer client)?

Comment: I just want to bring back the data and then populate a repeater control in an ASP page (using C#).  I guess I could just run the code in C#, but I was trying to replicate exactly what I did when we used SQL Server.  We're using Oracle 12c.

Comment: I have no idea how you'd call a procedure from there; quite likely you want a ref cursor out variable, or a function that returns a ref cursor, if your SQL Server code was just seeing the result of the query. [There's a 12c-specific method here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40360471/266304). I think, from comments I've seen, that is supposed to be close to how it works in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

if you call a select inside the PL/SQL you normally do this to calculate with the results inside the procedure. You have two ways:

```
Select ... into ... from ...
```

if you want to select one row.

or you declare a cursor as select and loop through it.

But I think, you want a stored procedure, that calculates a result as table.

It seems you want to do something like

```
SELECT * FROM MyProcedure(12345);
```

So you probably should look here [oracle procedure returning table of custom data type record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433506/oracle-procedure-returning-table-of-custom-data-type-record)